# First column of Householder matrix is a multiple of $x$, where $Hx=||x_{2}e_{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need help proving that the first column of $H$ is a multiple of $x$, where $x$ is  nonzero and $H$ is such that $Hx=||x||_{2}e_{1}$.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the title, this is my first question.

Comment: Is there more context surrounding this question?

Comment: $H$ is a Householder matrix, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column of $H$ is $He_1$.

An important property of $H$ is $H^2 = I$.

In particular, this shows $H(He_1)=e_1$.

One can then show $He_1$ is nonzero (else $0=H0=HHe_1=e_1$, a contradiction).

Using the fact that $H$ is symmetric, one can also show $\|He_1\|^2 = e_1^\top H^\top H e_1 = e_1^\top HHe_1 = e_1^\top e_1 = 1$.

Thus with $x=He_1$, we have shown $Hx = HHe_1 = e_1 = \|x\| e_1$.